# Why am I unable to create overviews in QGIS despite having disk space

Tags: qgis-3, remote-sensing, gdaladdo, map-overviews

I have 120 GeoTIFF files, totalling around 250GB of data.

Files names are from `1.tif` to `120.tif`.

I tried to create overviews for all the files in one go using`gdaladdo` in terminal. While overviews got created till `50.tif`, for the rest of the files I got the `no more space on disk` error. I checked and indeed my drive partition (264GB) was full.

I moved the rest of the files to another partition on my disk, which had over 200 GB available.

Now when I create overviews using `gdaladdo` for these relocated files in their new location, I get the same error. This time I don't create the overviews using `gdaladdo` in terminal. Instead, I use QGIS. (I know QGIS also uses `gdaladdo` only internally, but I thought I should mention this.)

`ERROR 1: /media/nancy/G/51.tif:Failed to allocate memory for to read TIFF directory (0 elements of 12 bytes each)`

`ERROR 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Failed to read directory at offset 1195893042`

`0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.`

`Execution completed in 2.04 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/media/nancy/G/51.tif'}`

Also, on loading `51.tif` in QGIS and right clicking, I get a cross on all the resolutions of the overviews.

[image: cross on overview sizes]

This is not the case for some other rasters that I have in my `/home` directory. This same window for them shows all the overview resolutions possible to be made.

[image: QGIS window shows various overviews sizes]

What is wrong?

Comment: Error seems to suggest problem with memory `Failed to allocate memory for to read TIFF directory` but gdaladdo should not use so much memory. Is the original file `51.tif`tiled?

Comment: are you out of inodes? - try `df -ih` to check

Comment: Going a different direction, are you using compression? QGIS (at least recent versions) allows you to specify creation options for GTiff create options and pyramids options separately (under `Options / GDAL`). For command line `gdaladdo` you have to specify separately. Are the filesizes for the overlays you can create the same from command line and from QGIS?

Comment: @IanTurton I ran `df -ih`. It shows I have used only 1% of the available inodes in `/dev/sdb3` and `dev/sdb4`, which are the 2 disk partitions where I've saved these images.

Comment: @user30184 How do I know if a GeoTIFF is tiled? Running `gdalinfo` gives this https://ibb.co/QCrGK84

Comment: @Houska No, I did not use any compression. I just used this command to create overviews for all the 120 files in one go - `for i in *.tif; gdaladdo -r nearest -clean 2 4 8 16 $i; done`. I don't know how to see if the filesizes of the overviews created by command line & QGIS are different, because when I created the overviews, no new files got created in my folder. Just the empty space in the folder dropped to 0 GB, while before creating the overviews, around 50GB free space was there.

Comment: Block size 17717 tells that image is not tiled. Image data is saved as 17717 pixels wide rows. But the error in gdalinfo makes me wonder if the tiff file is corrupted. Can you convert it with `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate 51.tif 51_copy.tif`?